# Porque cuando se gana el juego la secuencia continua y no se respeta el remove event listener

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un simon(juego de memoria) cuando el nivel alcanza el ultimo nivel y se te anuncia que ganaste el juego, el valor level vuelve a 0 los divs no deberian tener event listeners y tampoco deberia reiniciarse la secuencia sola, ¿alguna idea para convertir eliminar y aregar eventos click en ciclos for?

```js
const boton = document.getElementById('btnEmpezar')

const verde = document.getElementById('verde')
const amarillo =  document.getElementById('amarillo')
const azul = document.getElementById('azul')
const rojo = document.getElementById('rojo')
const blanco = document.getElementById('blanco')
const loser = document.getElementById('loser')
const winner = document.getElementById('winner')
let level = 0
const ULTIMO_NIVEL = 1
let subnivel = 0
const colores = {
    verde, 
    amarillo,
    azul,
    rojo,
    blanco
}

let  secuencia = new Array(10).fill(0).map(n => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))


function hideButton(){
    boton.classList.add('hide')
    iluminarSecuencia()
}

function  iluminarSecuencia() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= level; i++) {
        const color = transformarNumeroAColor(secuencia[i])
        setTimeout(() => iluminarColor(color), 1000 * i)
        console.log(color)
    }
    agregarEventosClick()
}

function iluminarColor(color) {
    colores[color].classList.add('light')
    setTimeout(() => this.apagarColor(color), 350)
}

function apagarColor(color) {
    colores[color].classList.remove('light')
}

function transformarNumeroAColor(numero) {
    switch (numero) {
        case 0:
            return 'rojo'
        case 1:
            return 'verde'
        case 2:
            return 'amarillo'
        case 3:
            return 'azul'
        case 4:
            return 'blanco'
    }
}

function transformarColorANumero(color) {
    switch (color) {
        case 'rojo':
            return 0
        case 'verde':
            return 1
        case 'amarillo':
            return 2
        case 'azul':
            return 3
        case 'blanco':
            return 4
    }
}




function agregarEventosClick() {
    colores.verde.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.amarillo.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.rojo.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.azul.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.blanco.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
}

function eliminarEventosClick() {
    colores.verde.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.amarillo.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.rojo.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.azul.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.blanco.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
}

function  elegirColor(ev) {
    const nombreColor = ev.target.dataset.color
    const numeroColor = transformarColorANumero(nombreColor)
    iluminarColor(nombreColor)
    if (numeroColor === secuencia[subnivel]) {
        subnivel++

        if (subnivel > level) {
            eliminarEventosClick()
            level++
            subnivel=0

            setTimeout(iluminarSecuencia, 1500)
        }
        if (level === (ULTIMO_NIVEL + 1)) {
            ganoJuego()
        } 
    }
    else {
        perdioJuego()
    }
} 

function ganoJuego(){
    eliminarEventosClick()
    winner.classList.remove('hide')
    setTimeout(start, 1000)
}

function start(){
    winner.classList.add('hide')
    boton.classList.remove('hide')
    level=0
}

function perdioJuego(){
    eliminarEventosClick()
    loser.classList.remove('hide')
    setTimeout(startos, 1000)
}

function startos(){
    loser.classList.add('hide')
    boton.classList.remove('hide')
    level=0 
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gameboard{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: relative;
}

.polen{
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  top: calc(0% - 50px);
  left: calc(-20% - 200px);
}

.box{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px  solid black ;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.uno{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.767);
  position: relative;
}

.dos{
  background-color:  rgb(49, 122, 55);
}

.tres{
  background-color: rgb(213, 224, 46) ;
  position: relative;
}

.cuatro{
  background-color: rgb(194, 13, 13);
}

.petado{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(252, 255, 55);
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border-top-left-radius: 60%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:50% ;
}

.petado.light{
  background-color: rgb(252, 253, 201);
}

.petado.dark{
  background-color:rgb(195, 197, 48);
}

.petaun{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

.petaun.light{
  background-color: rgb(255, 129, 129);
}

.petaun.dark{
  background-color: rgb(177, 0, 0);
}

.petatre{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgb(79, 255, 88);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
}

.petatre.light{
  background-color: rgb(198, 253, 201);
}

.petatre.dark{
  background-color: rgb(67, 204, 74);
}

.petacua{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius:60% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.petacua.light{
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 255);
}

.petacua.dark{
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 211);
}

.polen{
  position:absolute;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: calc(50% - 33px);
  left:calc(50% - 33px);
}

.polen.light{
  background-color: rgb(133, 127, 127)
}

.polen.dark{
  background-color:rgb(207, 205, 205);
}

.boton{
  position:absolute;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(27, 26, 26);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: calc(50% - 31px);
  left:calc(50% - 30px);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.boton.hide{
  display: none;
}

.boton:hover{
  border: 1px solid rgb(10, 10, 10);
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-style: italic;
}

.boton:focus{
  outline:0;
}

.resultado{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 55px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.resultados{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 55px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.resultado.hide{
  display: none;
} 

.resultados.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gameboard">
    <div class="box uno light" >
      <div id='rojo' class="petaun" data-color="rojo" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box dos light">
      <div id="amarillo" class="petado" data-color="amarillo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box tres light" >
      <div id="verde" class="petatre" data-color="verde"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box cuatro light" >
      <div id="azul" class="petacua" data-color="azul"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="blanco" class="polen" data-color="blanco"></div>
    <button id="btnEmpezar" class="boton" onclick="hideButton()">Empezar!</button>

    <div id="winner" class="resultado hide"><p>Ganaste! :)</p></div>
    <div id="loser" class="resultados hide"><p> :( Perdiste!</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a [edit] y, una vez que estás en modo edición, pulsar Ctrl + M? Podrás incluir tu código de un modo mucho más cómodo para todos, por partes

Answer (score 1):

En la funcion `elegirColor` tienes puesto el timeout que hace que la secuencia se ilumine, y no lo cancelas. Para cancelarlo tienes que usar la función [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout). Asignas lo que devuelve el timeout a una variable, y en la función de ganar lo quitas.

```
// Poner un timeout en 1,5 segundos.
var valorTimeout = setTimeout(iluminarSecuencia, 1500);

// Eliminar el timeout.
clearTimeout(valorTimeout);
```

En el código de abajo he creado la variable `timeoutIluminacion` al principio, donde declaras las demás variables.

Luego en la función `elegirColor`, el timeout lo asigno a esa variable: `timeoutIluminacion = setTimeout(iluminarSecuencia, 1500)`.

Finalmente en `ganoJuego` quito ese timeout:
`clearTimeout(timeoutIluminacion);`

```js
const boton = document.getElementById('btnEmpezar')

const verde = document.getElementById('verde')
const amarillo =  document.getElementById('amarillo')
const azul = document.getElementById('azul')
const rojo = document.getElementById('rojo')
const blanco = document.getElementById('blanco')
const loser = document.getElementById('loser')
const winner = document.getElementById('winner')
let level = 0
const ULTIMO_NIVEL = 1
let subnivel = 0
const colores = {
    verde, 
    amarillo,
    azul,
    rojo,
    blanco
};
let timeoutIluminacion = null;

let secuencia = new Array(10).fill(0).map(n => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))

function hideButton(){
    boton.classList.add('hide')
    iluminarSecuencia()
}

function  iluminarSecuencia() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= level; i++) {
        const color = transformarNumeroAColor(secuencia[i])
        setTimeout(() => iluminarColor(color), 1000 * i)
        console.log(color)
    }
    agregarEventosClick()
}

function iluminarColor(color) {
    colores[color].classList.add('light')
    setTimeout(() => this.apagarColor(color), 350)
}

function apagarColor(color) {
    colores[color].classList.remove('light')
}

function transformarNumeroAColor(numero) {
    switch (numero) {
        case 0:
            return 'rojo'
        case 1:
            return 'verde'
        case 2:
            return 'amarillo'
        case 3:
            return 'azul'
        case 4:
            return 'blanco'
    }
}

function transformarColorANumero(color) {
    switch (color) {
        case 'rojo':
            return 0
        case 'verde':
            return 1
        case 'amarillo':
            return 2
        case 'azul':
            return 3
        case 'blanco':
            return 4
    }
}

function agregarEventosClick() {
    colores.verde.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.amarillo.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.rojo.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.azul.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.blanco.addEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
}

function eliminarEventosClick() {
    colores.verde.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.amarillo.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.rojo.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.azul.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
    colores.blanco.removeEventListener('click', this.elegirColor)
}

function  elegirColor(ev) {
    const nombreColor = ev.target.dataset.color
    const numeroColor = transformarColorANumero(nombreColor)
    iluminarColor(nombreColor)
    if (numeroColor === secuencia[subnivel]) {
        subnivel++

        if (subnivel > level) {
            eliminarEventosClick()
            level++
            subnivel=0

            timeoutIluminacion = setTimeout(iluminarSecuencia, 1500)
        }
        if (level === (ULTIMO_NIVEL + 1)) {
            ganoJuego()
        } 
    }
    else {
        perdioJuego()
    }
} 

function ganoJuego(){
    eliminarEventosClick();
    winner.classList.remove('hide');
    clearTimeout(timeoutIluminacion);
    setTimeout(start, 1000);
}

function start(){
    winner.classList.add('hide')
    boton.classList.remove('hide')
    level=0
}

function perdioJuego(){
    eliminarEventosClick()
    loser.classList.remove('hide')
    setTimeout(startos, 1000)
}

function startos(){
    loser.classList.add('hide')
    boton.classList.remove('hide')
    level=0 
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gameboard{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: relative;
}

.polen{
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  top: calc(0% - 50px);
  left: calc(-20% - 200px);
}

.box{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px  solid black ;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.uno{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.767);
  position: relative;
}

.dos{
  background-color:  rgb(49, 122, 55);
}

.tres{
  background-color: rgb(213, 224, 46) ;
  position: relative;
}

.cuatro{
  background-color: rgb(194, 13, 13);
}

.petado{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(252, 255, 55);
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border-top-left-radius: 60%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:50% ;
}

.petado.light{
  background-color: rgb(252, 253, 201);
}

.petado.dark{
  background-color:rgb(195, 197, 48);
}

.petaun{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}

.petaun.light{
  background-color: rgb(255, 129, 129);
}

.petaun.dark{
  background-color: rgb(177, 0, 0);
}

.petatre{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgb(79, 255, 88);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
}

.petatre.light{
  background-color: rgb(198, 253, 201);
}

.petatre.dark{
  background-color: rgb(67, 204, 74);
}

.petacua{
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius:60% ;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.petacua.light{
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 255);
}

.petacua.dark{
  background-color:rgb(0, 0, 211);
}

.polen{
  position:absolute;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: calc(50% - 33px);
  left:calc(50% - 33px);
}

.polen.light{
  background-color: rgb(133, 127, 127)
}

.polen.dark{
  background-color:rgb(207, 205, 205);
}

.boton{
  position:absolute;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(27, 26, 26);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: calc(50% - 31px);
  left:calc(50% - 30px);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.boton.hide{
  display: none;
}

.boton:hover{
  border: 1px solid rgb(10, 10, 10);
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-style: italic;
}

.boton:focus{
  outline:0;
}

.resultado{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 55px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.resultados{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 55px;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.resultado.hide{
  display: none;
} 

.resultados.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gameboard">
    <div class="box uno light" >
      <div id='rojo' class="petaun" data-color="rojo" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box dos light">
      <div id="amarillo" class="petado" data-color="amarillo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box tres light" >
      <div id="verde" class="petatre" data-color="verde"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box cuatro light" >
      <div id="azul" class="petacua" data-color="azul"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="blanco" class="polen" data-color="blanco"></div>
    <button id="btnEmpezar" class="boton" onclick="hideButton()">Empezar!</button>

    <div id="winner" class="resultado hide"><p>Ganaste! :)</p></div>
    <div id="loser" class="resultados hide"><p> :( Perdiste!</p></div>
</div>
```